# Checkerboard Expected Value Question

Tags: probability

A checker is placed in a random square of an ordinary $8\times 8$ checkerboard (with all squares being equally likely). Then, checkers are placed in all squares that are below and to the right of the first checker, including those that are directly below or directly to the right of the first checker. Here is an example where the first checker is shown in red:

[image: Example]

After this procedure, what is the expected value of the number of checkers on the board?

Comment: Hint: There are 64 equally likely outcomes.

Comment: @vadim123: That would be doing it the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 64 possibilities. If we start in the bottom corner and move left we traverse the possibilities of 1 to 8 checkers. For the next row we go 2, 4, ..., 16 or twice the first row. The third row is three times the first. And so on. Thus, the expected value,

$$\frac{1}{64}\left( (1+2+3+\cdots+8) + 2(1+2+3+\cdots+8) +3(1+2+3+\cdots+8) + \cdots +8(1+2+3+\cdots+8)   \right)$$

The sum $1+2+3+\cdots+8=\frac{8\cdot 9}{2} = 36$. Thus, the expected value is,

$$\frac{1}{64}\left( 36 + 2\cdot 36+ 3\cdot 36+ \cdots +8\cdot 36   \right) = \frac{36(1+2+3+\cdots +8)}{64} = \frac{36^2}{64} = \frac{81}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of squares below the first checker, including the first checker itself. Let $Y$ be the number of squares to the right of the first checker, including the first checker itself. Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables, each uniformly distributed on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. The expected number of checkers on the board is

$$E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)=\frac{1+8}2\cdot\frac{1+8}2=\frac{81}4.$$